# I bought Minecraft for Windows 10 for my son before buying Minecraft Java. How do I merge?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

My son has built worlds in the Windows 10 edition and has been making mods in IntelliJ IDEA (the ID Tech camp package). He can't open the worlds from Windows 10 Edition in Java Edition and his IntelliJ mods automatically point to the Windows 10 Edition. I would appreciate any help in merging the two instances, especially linking his mods to the full Minecraft Java Edition. Thanks!

For any other parents who may view this question, I highly recommend avoiding the Microsoft version. I feel like I double paid for the same game, since he needed Minecraft Java Edition for his camp.

Comment: When you say Minecraft for Windows 10, you talk about the Bedrock edition right?

Answer (score 4):

The Minecraft Java Edition and the Windows 10 Edition (Bedrock Edition) are coded differently.

At the moment, there is *no way to redeem the Java Edition by buying the Windows 10 version* (coded in C++). In the other way, previously, there was a possibility to redeem the Win 10 version with a Minecraft Java Edition.

Answer (score 3):

There are currently 2 versions of Minecraft, Bedrock and Java.

#### Bedrock

This is the version on most devices.  If you play on a console, mobile device, or go through the Windows store, this is the version you are using.  It's designed to allow players on all platforms to play together.

#### Java

This is the way the game was originally developed and has been continually updated through all the other versions.  Usually has the most up-to-date features.

The problem you seem to be facing is that the different versions save their data in different formats.  While it is possible to migrate a world from one to the other, the results are not 100% accurate.  On top of the world not matching after migration, inventories and things like maps and chests may also break, causing you to re-do a lot of work.

If you still want to go through with a migration, searching for something along the lines of "convert Minecraft worlds bedrock to Java" will give tools that can assist.  One that I've used for migrating from Bedrock to Java was [MCC Toolchest PE](http://mcctoolchest.com/Download), but again, it's not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this. Windows 10 Edition and Java Edition are two completely different games behind the scenes. As others have stated, it's possible, but you're risking corruptions. Also the mods will never work with Java Edition.

Also, Bedrock Edition is not objectively worse than Java Edition. In fact, I'd say that for most kids, it's the better option, as they can play with their friends who play on mobile, consoles, and TV's.

(Don't @ me, I started with Pocket Edition, but have since played Java and absolutely love it [I'm a nerd :P]